# How can I correlate my 2 queries?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have this basic query here, and I want the results of the second column to correlate to an outer/related query:

```
    SELECT 
        r1.OrderNo,
        COUNT(r1.PartNo) AS [Pcs Complete]
    FROM OrderRouting r1
    WHERE r1.Status = 'Current'
        AND r1.WorkCntr = 'Shipping'
    GROUP BY r1.OrderNo
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

So what I'm trying is to put the second column in my select list of my outer query, so it looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(r.OrderNo AS INT) AS OrderNo,
        (
        SELECT 
            r1.OrderNo,
            COUNT(r1.PartNo)
        FROM OrderRouting r1
        WHERE r1.Status = 'Current'
            AND r1.WorkCntr = 'Shipping'
        GROUP BY r1.OrderNo
        ) AS [Pcs Complete]
FROM OrderRouting r 
    JOIN OrderDet od ON r.JobNo = od.JobNo
    JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderNo = o.Orderno
WHERE r.Status = 'Current'
        AND r.WorkCntr IN ('Cutting', 'Framing', 'Assembly', 'Shipping')
GROUP BY CAST(r.OrderNo AS INT)
```

Now obviously this doesn't work since the inner select only allows 1 column, but if I remove the r1.OrderNo column, I get 1 aggregate applied to every value in my outer query, which is not what I want.  How do I correlate them?  I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(r.OrderNo AS INT) AS OrderNo,
        (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(r1.PartNo)
        FROM OrderRouting r1
        WHERE r1.Status = 'Current'
            AND r1.WorkCntr = 'Shipping'
        ) AS [Pcs Complete]
FROM OrderRouting r 
    JOIN OrderDet od ON r.JobNo = od.JobNo
    JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderNo = o.Orderno
WHERE r.Status = 'Current'
        AND r.WorkCntr IN ('Cutting', 'Framing', 'Assembly', 'Shipping')
GROUP BY CAST(r.OrderNo AS INT)
```

OUTPUT (Wrong!):

[image]

And this:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(r.OrderNo AS INT) AS OrderNo,
        (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(r1.PartNo)
        FROM OrderRouting r1 JOIN OrderRouting r ON r1.OrderNo = r.OrderNo
        WHERE r1.Status = 'Current'
            AND r1.WorkCntr = 'Shipping'
        ) AS [Pcs Complete]
FROM OrderRouting r 
    JOIN OrderDet od ON r.JobNo = od.JobNo
    JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderNo = o.Orderno
WHERE r.Status = 'Current'
        AND r.WorkCntr IN ('Cutting', 'Framing', 'Assembly', 'Shipping')
GROUP BY CAST(r.OrderNo AS INT)
```

Neither worked, they both returned 1 aggregate applied across the board that isn't related to my OrderNo column in the outer query at all.  Perhaps I need to try something else, I just need some guidance on what is the best way to accomplish what I need. Thx in advance

Comment: Provide sample data from all tables (as `create` and `insert` queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the left join to show all existing order number.

```
SELECT CAST(r.OrderNo AS INT) AS OrderNo,
    r2.[Pcs Complete]
FROM OrderRouting r 
JOIN OrderDet od ON r.JobNo = od.JobNo
JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderNo = o.Orderno
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT CAST(r1.OrderNo AS INT) OrderNo,
            COUNT(r1.PartNo) AS [Pcs Complete]
        FROM OrderRouting r1
        WHERE r1.Status = 'Current'
            AND r1.WorkCntr = 'Shipping'
        GROUP BY r1.OrderNo
    ) AS [r2] ON r2.OrderNo = r.OrderNo
WHERE r.Status = 'Current'
AND r.WorkCntr IN ('Cutting', 'Framing', 'Assembly', 'Shipping')
GROUP BY CAST(r.OrderNo AS INT)
```

Comment: I don't know what you just did, but that was godlike, worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but I think the code below will get you on the right path:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(r.OrderNo AS INT) AS OrderNo
FROM OrderRouting r 
    JOIN OrderDet od ON r.JobNo = od.JobNo
    JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderNo = o.Orderno
    JOIN
    (
            SELECT r1.OrderNo,
            COUNT(r1.PartNo)
        FROM OrderRouting r1 JOIN OrderRouting r ON r1.OrderNo = r.OrderNo
        WHERE r1.Status = 'Current'
            AND r1.WorkCntr = 'Shipping'
    ) AS [PCsComplete] ON PcsComplete.OrderNo = r.OrderNo
WHERE r.Status = 'Current'
        AND r.WorkCntr IN ('Cutting', 'Framing', 'Assembly', 'Shipping')
GROUP BY CAST(r.OrderNo AS INT)
```

Comment: Your answer was pretty much on the right track, thanks